# Translated JPG image served via Mapserver WMS not displaying

Tags: wms, mapserver, gdal-translate

I am experiencing a problem while serving an image via WMS (Mapserver). The image is translated (gdal_translate) with gcp and then warped (gdal_warp) to 4326. The issue is that the image is shown correctly in QGIS, but when I try to serve it via a Mapserver WMS it is not displayed. When the WMS is added to QGIS I can "zoom to extent" correctly, but the image is blank (filename: usr_14_upld_1063_sn_0.JPG).

I have a similar image (usr_14_upld_1064_sn_0.JPG) in the same approximate area which is displayed correctly via QGIS (simply added and as a WMS).

The same happens when I try to store the image via Mapserver's shp2img.exe
shp2img states:

> [Sat Aug 26 09:46:12 2023].271000 msDrawRasterLayerGDAL(): Entering
> transform. [Sat Aug 26 09:46:12 2023].271000 msDrawRasterLayerGDAL():
> no apparent overlap between map view and this window(1). [Sat Aug 26
> 09:46:12 2023].271000 msDrawMap(): Layer 0 (UPLD_MOSAIC_1063), 0.017s

I have placed the relevant files into [this shared folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eKYHXP5die20mLYvwa7If_bmN4Qsmnr8?usp=sharing) for testing.

Can you shed some light into this matter?

Comment: Can't see anything obvious, probably something for MapServer issues

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the test files and tried a map2img command with MapServer 8.0.1 and got a blank image. I think there is a problem with the XML metadata file.
If you make a copy of `usr_14_upld_1064_sn_0.JPG.aux.xml` and rename it `usr_14_upld_1063_sn_0.JPG.aux.xml` (replacing the original), then I get output:

```
map2img -m test.map -conf C:\MapServer\apps\mapserver.conf -o test.jpg
```

[image]

I made one change to the Mapfile by adding `SIZE 1000 1000`.